# Clone a VirtualBox VDI to make a second DRBD node

Tags: virtualbox, drbd, cloning, data-consistency

A primary node has been built up in a VirtualBox (guest RHEL 6 + DRBD).

In order to get a second node with the same configuration, a VirtualBox cloning operation seems ideal

- easiness
- declare the second node DRBD secondary: `drbdadm secondary resource`
- no need to sync the DRBD data (at first glance)

However I was wondering: is that enough of a setup, or does DRBD creates unique data per host, and it'd be better to do another `drbdadm create-md` on second node (then sync)?

(*Edit: Virtual platform setup to perform tests*)

Comment: What the heck are you doing? Is this just a proof-of-concept?

Comment: @ewwhite Considering the environment you may guess it's not a critical HA platform we're building, but rather a mini test setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is possible. It is called truck-based replication and only really makes sense if there would be a lot of data to sync from primary to secondary.
See http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/s-using-truck-based-replication.html

For testing purposes I would clone the machine but then create the secondary DRBD device from scratch (or read through the manual on how to use truck based replication).

Comment: This will also give you experience and familiarity with the commands you'll need to use when setting up the production instance, assuming this being tested in advance of a production setup.